# Singular photon absorption of electron in orbital motion

Tags: photons

While the free electrons at rest can absorb photons having very different periods $T_γ$, as photoelectric effect proves, the free electrons in orbital motion can absorb only photons whose period $T_γ$ is equal to their orbital period $T_{orb} = 2πr/v$, where $r$ is their orbital radius and $v$ is their linear velocity. This fact is proved by the free electrons in cyclotron motion in an uniform magnetic field $B$, which can absorb exclusively photons with period $T_γ = h/2M_{B}B = 2πm/eB$, where $h$ is the Planck’s constant, $M_B = eh/4πm$ is the Bohr magneton, $e$ is the elementary electric charge and $m$ is the electron mass, no matter what orbital radius $r$ and linear velocity $v$ the electrons have (P. Ekstrom and D. Wineland, *The Isolated Electron*, Sc. Amer. $243$ (2), (1980) 90). Or, these electrons have always an identical orbital period $T_{orb} = 2πr/v = h/2M_{B}B = 2πm/eB$, also irrespective of their orbital radius $r = mv/eB$ and linear velocity $v$.

How can this singular photon absorption $T_γ = T_{orb}$ be explained, especially as the two periods $T_γ$ and $T_{orb}$ belong to antagonistic scopes of physics, first to wave theory, the second to body mechanics?

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else we must decide what means the period $T_γ$ of a photon.

Already for a long time, photons have been seen as pointlike elementary particles with mass $m_γ$, momentum $I_γ = m_{γ}c$ and intrinsic spin $L_γ = h/2π$, but whose motion in substance is guided by a wave train of about $1m$ long (macroscopic length found for all photons from interference experiments). At first sight $T_γ$ should be assigned to this attached wave train, but yet this simplest option has to be abandoned, because the energy $E_γ = h/T_γ$ of a photon is just a property of its mass $m_γ$, $E_γ = h/m_{γ}c^2$, and therefore $T_γ$ has to be connected, one way or other, with the corpuscular part of the photon, not at all with that wave train ad hoc attached to all photons only for an easy-going justification of phenomena as their diffraction or interference (long before noticed on macroscopic waves in air or water). But, on the other hand, how could a corpuscular pointlike photon have its own period $T_γ$ (or its own frequency $ν_γ = 1/T_γ$), as long as nor yet that saving syntagm “intrinsic property” cannot be considered in this case, just because photons have periods $T_γ$ varying between wide limits?

It is very clear, this experimentally noticed strict correlation $T_γ = T_{orb}$ is definitively incompatible with the concept of pointlike photon. It could get a sense only if photons are composite elementary particles, whose identical subquantum constituents are successively absorbed by an electron in an elementary act of photon absorption (or emitted by an electron in an elementary act of photon emission). And the most natural first step on this way is to identify these subquantum constituents of photons with that “just one kind of particle” existing at distances of the order of $10^{-31} m$ (H. Georgi, Sc. Amer. 244 (4), 1981, 40), and even with that “universal matter” (W. Heisenberg, *Physics & Pilosophie*, 1959) or “general basic material” (K. N. Mukhin, *Experimental Nuclear Physics*, 1974) from which all elementary particles are “moulded in different forms”.

The second necessary step is to find an inner structure of photons able to justify the known properties of them, beginning just with their own period $T_γ$, which appoint directly their energy, $E_γ = h/T_γ$. Or, the simplest corpuscular structure having its own period (or frequency) is evidently the linear beam of identical subparticles evenly spread on a line coincident with their common direction of motion with linear velocity $c$. The constant distance between two consecutive subparticles can be called the wavelength $λ_γ$ of this linear beam photon, wherefrom it results its period $T_γ = λ_{γ}/c$ and frequency $ν_γ = c/λ_γ$.

In addition, there is a supplementary essential condition for this model of corpuscular photons with inner structure: all photons of this kind should have the same emission time $τ_γ$, because only so their period $T_γ$ is inversely proportional with the number $n_s$ of their constituent subparticles, $n_s = τ_{γ}/T_γ$, and therefore inversely proportional also with their energy, $E_γ = n_{s}m_{s}c^2 = h/T_γ$, where $m_s$ is the mass of each subquantum particle in the linear beam photons. And this unique emission time $τ_γ$ can be easy obtained because it is equal to the highest possible period $T_{γ(max)}$ of a linear beam photon, that one of of the linear beam photon made of only two subquantum particles. As this highest period correspond to the lower limit $ν_{γ(min)} = 4.08\cdot10^8 Hz$ found by Wilson and Penzias for universal background of microwaves, $T_{γ(max)} = 1/ν_{γ(min)}$, it results $τ_γ = T_{γ(max)} = 2.451\cdot10^{-9} s$. Of course, this unique emission time means a unique length of all linear beam photons, $l_ γ = cτ_γ = 0.735 m$.

As seen, the above calculated $τ_γ$ and $l_ γ$ agree with experimental data well known for long, for example the emission (or absorption) time $τ_γ = 2.451\cdot10^{-9} s$ with the time of about $2-3 ns$ experimentally measured for fluorescence extinction or the light scintillations in scintillators, the time interval of about $2-3 ns$ from lighting an atomic lattice until the appearance of the first photoelectrons, or the time equal to some few $nanoseconds$ measured for light pulses appearing by electrical discharges in gases, and so on, while the unique length $l_ γ = 0.735 m$ of all beam photons agrees very well with that of about $1m$ measured for the wave train attached to the pointlike photon in quantum physics.

Significantly, the mass $m_s$ of the subquantum particles constituent of the linear beam photons, but as well as of all radiating elementary particles, is $m_s = m_{0}/τ_{γ}ν_{a} ≈ 0.3\cdot10^{-11}m_{0}$ (or $~0.5\cdot10^{-6}eV$), where $m_0$ is the rest mass of the electron and $ν_{a} = 1.234\cdot10^{20}Hz$ is the frequency of photons resulted from electron-positron annihilation at rest, therefore in good agreement with the mass experimentally estimated for the so-called *axions*, subquantum particles presumed in the last years to be the unique constituents of all elementary particles.

This multiple compatibility with various experimental data is undoubtedly very significant for confirming the corpuscular model of linear beam photon, but the most important fact in this regard is the unique ability of this structural model of composite photon to justify the singular photon absorption $T_γ = T_{orb}$ experimentally noticed for the electron in orbital motion.